# URDF/XACRO RViz could not parse visual elements

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-melodic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to make a URDF model and view it in Rviz. However, when I try to display the URDF model with RVIZ, it just spits out the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1586312501.638016618]: Could not parse visual element for Link [fl_module_base]
[ERROR] [1586312501.638561453]: Could not parse visual element for Link [base]
[ERROR] [1586312502.490229106]: Could not parse visual element for Link [fl_module_base]
[ERROR] [1586312502.490260233]: Could not parse visual element for Link [base]
```

Although the URDF is generated through a XACRO, I tried changing the .urdf file directly, with the same issue. It seems like the error is thrown just for the visual tag being where it is. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Or is this just a bug? The URDF I am using is also below:

Cheers!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from base.urdf.xacro   | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="base">
  <link name="fl_module_base">
    <visual>
      <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <link name="base">
    <visual>
      <cylinder length="0.2" radius="0.2"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base"/>
    <child link="fl_module_base"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
   </joint>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348745/urdf/xacro-rviz-could-not-parse-visual-elements/) by [alextac98](https://answers.ros.org/users/32942/alextac98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is things missing in your code.
To use the tag cylinder you **must** before opening the tag geometry:

```
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                 <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
```

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2020-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-08**:
A link to [wiki/urdf/XML/link](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link) may be informative for the OP.

**Comment by [alextac98](https://answers.ros.org/users/32942/alextac98/) on 2020-04-08**:
Yeah that's what happens when you code at midnight. Thank you!